# Grammar of "Love is the pearl of great worth"

Tags: grammar

According to the book I read, "Love is the pearl of great worth" is grammatically wrong. Why is it? (It says "the" is [sic].)

Comment: Related if not a dupe: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-article-usage-a-vs-the-vs-none and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22508/definite-or-indefinite-article-in-the-a-devils-advocate . Also see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28935/the-usage-of-sic-in-writing for an explanation of the usage of _[sic]_.

Comment: @coleopterist That article on [sic] shows its use to sneer at non-standard English. Although its use to annotate factual inaccuracies (as opposed to solecisms) is mentioned in passing in the answers there, I don't think they suffice to answer why [sic] appears in this case.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 4):

It is not ungrammatical. The choice between the definite and the indefinite article depends on the context, and on what exactly the writer is trying to say.

The origin of the expression is biblical. It occurs in Matthew 13:46 of the King James Bible as

> Who, when he had found one pearl of great price, went and sold all
>   that he had, and bought it.

Google returns 71,300,000 hits for ‘the pearl of great worth’ and 87,700.000 for ‘a pearl of great worth’. The figures for ‘the pearl of great prce’ and ‘a pearl of great price’ are roughly the same at more than 38,000,000.

This [nGram graph](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20pearl%20of%20great%20price,%20the%20pearl%20of%20great%20price&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows a narrowing of the gap between both ‘the pearl of great worth’ and ‘a pearl of great worth’. [This one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20pearl%20of%20great%20worth,the%20pearl%20of%20great%20worth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that ‘a pearl of great worth’ is comparatively rare, and doesn’t show ‘the pearl of great worth’ at all.

Comment: I'm not sure this really explains ***why***. It does indeed depend on what the writer intends. Almost certainly the writer is familiar with the biblical original, and assumes his reader will be too. So by using *the*, he intends to *make reference to* that original, rather than *explicitly repeat/re-use it*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. You have greater confidence than I have in contemporary knowledge of the scriptures.

Comment: I doubt that! Anyway, I bet *you* knew or at least suspected the origin. But if you look at the comparatively few instances in print using *"the"*, I think you'll agree they do seem to be targeted at a readership you might well expect to be more familiar with biblical quotes than the average Joe. And it *did* seem to pop up around the time of the Great Depression, perhaps a time when more people might have been looking for some metaphorical/metaphysical pearl to compensate for the failure of Mammon to deliver the goods!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably reword it as "Love is **a** pearl of great worth."
Using "the" implies that there can only be one "pearl of great worth."

Comment: That's exactly what the writer _is_ implying here. Actually, the Bible uses the metaphor for (the difficulty but advisability of diligently trying to 'find') the Kingdom of Heaven. Showing love is a / the? key to being accepted into the Kingdom; the Kingdom is the realm where the atmosphere is 'righteousness, peace and joy' (Romans 14:17). Matthew 19:24ff shows that getting into the Kingdom of God is impossible for unaided man - it's not that God's mean, but He has unattainable (to us) standards - we aren't that loving. John 14:6; 10:9 and 3:16 give rather better news for pearl-seekers.

Answer (score 0):

The book editor is taking issue with the **content** indicating with *sic* that there is indeed more than one pearl of great worth, not that the sentence is incorrect **grammatically**. The literal meaning of *sic* is *thus*, and the editor is reiterating that this is the original version. If I were writing on the well-known poem "[On First Looking into Chapman's Homer](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/study_guide/literature/keats-poems/summary-analysis/first-looking-into-chapmans-homer/original-text.html)", which ends

> Then felt I like some watcher of the skies
>  When a new planet swims into his ken;
> Or like stout Cortez [sic] when with eagle eyes
>  He star'd at the Pacific — and all his men
> Look'd at each other with a wild surmise —
>  
>   Silent, upon a peak in Darien.

I have added the *sic* because it was the explorer **Bilbao**, not Cortez, who discovered the Pacific Ocean (for Europeans, Asians and Native Americans having discovered it long ago).

In my amateur reading of the original usage in the Biblical verse, the implication is that the Kingdom of Heaven is indeed a uniquely valuable pearl, of the greatest price, which may have influenced the author.

Answer (score 0):

By adding [sic] I don't think the editor necessarily implies any criticism. As is normal in such cases, he's simply making sure the reader doesn't assume there might have been a transcription error.

In fact, I'd say almost certainly the writer *deliberately* chose to use the definite article "**the**", even though most readers would be expecting the indefinite article "**a**" in that context.

The writer is making an oblique reference to **the** "proverbial pearl". He could have various reasons for doing this, but one possibility is he doesn't want the reader to think he's just passing off a tired old cliché as his own "creative prose". And the editor is just making sure the reader realises that.

---

EDIT: OP hasn't provided us with the original source, but I found [half-a-dozen](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22do%20this%20more%20than%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22love%20is%20the%20pearl%20of%20great%22&oq=%22love%20is%20the%20pearl%20of%20great%22&gs_l=serp.3...33784.36560.3.38069.12.12.0.0.0.0.80.558.12.12.0.cpsugrpqhmoffline..0.0...1c.1.Lu4r37TwjZU&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=b87632cebbad3757&biw=1351&bih=889) candidates in Google Books (the earliest seems to be 1928). It's worth flagging up the quote marks in [this one](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=su3rJxslp5gC&pg=PA189&dq=%22love%20is%20the%20pearl%20of%20great%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lZQIUarSGISa1AWGroDwCw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22love%20is%20the%20pearl%20of%20great%22&f=false) (from 1931), where it's **love is the "pearl of great price"**. Not to indicate a special usage or an unusual phrase just coined by the writer, but to show it's a known (to many) "quote". Notice how the definite article *isn't* included within the quote marks. I'm quite happy to accept that OP's writer felt his more clued-up readers would recognise the sense without that distracting punctuation.